# Отправить файл с помощью cURL

Tags: php

Скопировал код из мануала

```js
  $ch = curl_init('http://news/');

  $cfile = new CURLFile('/pic.jpg','image/jpg','test_name');

  $data = array('test_file' => $cfile);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  print $result;
  curl_close($ch);
```

Положил файл в ту же директорию.
На принимающей стороне распечатываю файл.

```
var_dump($_FILES);
```

Но ничего ответа нет.

Comment: `/pic.jpg`  - тут нужен полный путь. Вряд ли файл лежит в корне файловой системы. Или у вас там chroot?

Answer (score 1):

```
$cfile = new CURLFile( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/pic.jpg','image/jpg','test_name');
```